# HttpErrors - How to specify custom error page in relative path in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, http-error

I am trying to set relative path in  tag in web.config of MVC application. it is not working. below is code. but If I put in root directory then it worked.

Not working -

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace"  >
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
    <error statusCode="404" path="~/Views/Shared/404.html" responseMode="File"/>
 </httpErrors>
```

Working -

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace"  >
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
    <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
 </httpErrors>
```

I am getting message-

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
> changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I should get (I have mentioned below message in 404.html)-

> Page Not found.

How to set relative path?

Comment: `responseMode=file` means its a `file path` so have you tried `Views\Shared\404.html` **note** `\ not /`

Comment: Thanks. It worked with this - Views/Shared/404.html